Why the Electrical field is that way?
So, I asked my teacher to draw the incident and reflected wave in the case of the incidence onto a perfect electric conductor. The thing I Don’t undersand is why the reflected field is that way. The incident wave is in the left side btw and its polarization is something like (-ax+by). But the the reflected wave, has the componente of electric field in the positive X and Y axis. Since reflection coeffient is -1 in the case of a PEC, shouldn’t be the component of the reflected field in the positive X-axis (as it is in the picture) and on the negative Y-axis?

This question is a repost of How can we derive the polarization of reflected electric field?. Please do not repost questions. Instead, edit the original post.
